# angular chart js type line setting chart-options not working

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

Hi I'm trying to configure the graph to be without any tooltips or legends, and it look's like all the configured options are ignored. what I'm doing wrong?

it's the js object:

```
$scope.options = {
    segmentShowStroke : false,
     elements: { arc: { borderWidth: 0 } ,  point: {
          radius: 0
        }},
     tooltips:{
            enabled:false
        },
    legend: {
             display: false
        },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          id: 'y-axis-1',
          type: 'linear',
          display: false,
          position: 'left'
        }

      ]
    }
  };
```

And it's the canvas element :

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line"
chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options"
chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride"
chart-click="onClick" height="40px" width="1000px"
chart-colors="graph.colors" style=" width: 1000px; ;max-height: 40px !important;">
</canvas>
```

Comment: You have syntax errors on your canvas element and attributes.

Comment: Are you getting any error in your console?

Comment: yes i saw and fixed the html. and no there are no errors in the console

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
options : {
    scales : {
        xAxes : [ {
            gridLines : {
                display : false
            }
        } ]
    }
}
```

Comment: still ignoring all the options object

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work, only after changing the options from chartjsProvider.setOptions like this

```
ChartJsProvider.setOptions('line',{
        segmentShowStroke : false,
         elements: { arc: { borderWidth: 0 } ,  point: {
              radius: 0
            }},
         tooltips:{
                enabled:false
            },
        legend: {
                 display: false
            },
        scales: {
             yAxes: [
                     {

                       display: false,

                     }

                   ],
                   xAxes: [
                           {

                             display: false,

                           }

                         ]
        }
    });
```